# jQuery galleryview start autoplay on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleryview

I'm currently developping a website using the GalleryView plugin (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/). Everything works great, except there is no "start autoplay on mouseout" option (equivalent to stop on hover), so I'm trying to implement one myself. When I look trough the javascript code, I can see there is a "showNext" method which I'd like to call after a certain amount of time the user has not moused over the gallery. Here's a short version of the code I'm using (which is not working) :

```
$j(function(){
 sliderr = $j('#productGallery').galleryView({
    transition_speed: 600,
    autoplay: false 
    });
```

});

```
$j('.gallery-wrapper').mouseout(function(){

    if (timer == null) {
       timer = setInterval( function(){
          if (counter > 5000) {
             sliderr.galleryView("showNext");
             counter = 0;
          } else
             counter += 1000;
       }, 1000);
    } 
});
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with this code?

Comment: If you set `autoplay: true` does the slideshow resume?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at their demo, I suspect that there is a better way to do this. In the demo, they have a pause/play button that makes use of their `startSlideshow()` and `stopSlideShow()` functions. I suspect you will want to use that function, and accordingly, that you'll want to use a `setTimeout()` call instead of `setInterval()`. Something like this:

```
$j('.gallery-wrapper').mouseout(function(){
    timer = setTimeout( function(){
          //note: I'm not sure this is a function of the galleryView object
          //      it might be off of another part of the overall structure
          //      like sliderr.startSlideshow() or something.
          sliderr.galleryView.startSlideshow(); 
    }, 5000); 
});
```

And you'll probably want a corresponding `mouseover` to clear the timeout:

```
$j('.gallery-wrapper').mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, it's probably a better way to call start/stop slideshow method. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error in the console with the code you've supplied : `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (options) {
  if (this.length) {
   return this.each(function () {
    var gallery = Object.create(GalleryView);
    gallery.init(options,this);
   });
  }
 } has no method 'startSlideshow' `

Comment: Right. That's where my comment in the code about not being sure where the base was for the `startSlideshow()` function. I don't have an implementation to play with to figure that part out, and unfortunately I can't take the time to create one right now, so you'll have to experiment to see where in the chain that function actually exists. You might be able to get there from looking at their base demo.